# How to create PDF document outline (TOC) with lilypond?

Tags: lilypond

I have a document with multiple pieces and a Table of Contents. MWE:

```
\markuplist \table-of-contents

\tocItem "Song 1"
\score {
    \new Staff { c d e }
    \header { piece = "Song 1" }
}

\tocItem "Song 2"
\score {
    \new Staff { c d e }
    \header { piece = "Song 2" }
}
```

This works as expected, except that Lilypond doesn't write a PDF Document Outline (the thing marked in red in the following screenshot, I'm not quite sure how this is called, which is also why I found it difficult search for my problem).

[image]

I'd really like to have that in my PDF document. Does anyone know how I can make lilypond create such an outline?

Comment: This is called "PDF bookmarks". I manage to find that this is not supported yet in LilyPond. See this discussion here: http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/pdf-bookmarks-td233680.html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe this is now supported in LilyPond 2.22, as suggested by this note in the [list of changes](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/changes/):

> PDF bookmarks are now supported and allow for \tocItem entries to appear in the ‘table of contents’ panel of PDF viewers that support it.

Comment: I'm using 2.22.2 and PDF bookmarks did not generate for my table of contents.